# Observable async pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, ionic3, observable, angular-pipe

I'm attaching an Observable (menuitems$) in my AppComponent using:

```
<h2 *ngFor="let menuitem of menuitems$ | async">DEFAULT TEXT</h2>
```

In my AppComponent's .ts file I create the menuitems Observable:

```
this.menuitems$ = this.wordPressMenuService.getMenu(2).map(m => m.items);
```

And in my AppComponent's .ts file I subscribe again using:

```
this.menuitems$.subscribe(menuitems => { console.log(menuitems); });
```

The .subscribe returns data and logs it into the console, but binding it with the Async-pipe to the H2-tag (also tried different tags) does not render the h2-tags on the screen. No (console) error output.

My MenuService looks like this:

```
protected readonly menus$ = new Subject<WordPressMenu>();

constructor(private dataService:DataService) { }

getMenu(id:number) : Observable<WordPressMenu> {
    this.dataService.get<WordPressMenu>(AppSettings.WP_MENU_ENDPOINT + id).subscribe(data => {
        this.menus$.next(data);
    });
    return this.menus$.filter(m => m.ID == id);
}
```

**Update:** It works when I remove the subscribe(), but still didn't find out why you can't subscribe to the same observable with subscribe() and template-binding. So using the code below works, but why does it have to be a seperate Observable?

```
this.menuitems1$ = this.wordPressMenuService.getMenu(2).map(m => m.items);
this.menuitems2$ = this.wordPressMenuService.getMenu(2).map(m => m.items);
```

Comment: Define `does not work`. What are you observing while you are debugging?

Comment: The only thing I can see is that the h2-tags are not being rendered. Using the async-pipe and .subscribe() should do the same thing, but in this case it does not. .subscribe() works, the async-pipe doesn't do anything.

Comment: have you tried having the async pipe by itself? no subscribe.

Comment: Interesting. Removing the (seperate) subscribe fixes it. But the whole point of having observables is to have them on multiples places in your application, isn't it? And I need this seperate subscribe() for different functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is your `dataService.get().subscribe` in your getMenu method is finishing before the async pipe subscribes. So the async pipe never receives the subject's emissions. If possible, I would avoid using the subject and just return the `get` observable

```
getMenu(id:number) : Observable<WordPressMenu> {
    return this.dataService.get<WordPressMenu>(AppSettings.WP_MENU_ENDPOINT + id)
        .map(data => data.filter(m => m.ID == id));
    });
}
```

Comment: In the getMenu method, this.$menus.next() is being called, this should update the Observables, right?

Comment: @ErwinOkken if you subscribe before next is called. When you subscribe to a subject, you only receive emissions if next is called at a later time. What I believe is happening is next is called, then the async pipe subscribes, so the async pipe never receives the emission.

Comment: @ErwinOkken another potential solution is to use a ReplaySubject which will emit the last x emissions. Say you use ReplaySubject(1) (emit 1 previous emission), in this case when you subscribe you receive the last previous emission. So even if the next occurs before the subscribe, you will receive that emission when you subscribe.

Comment: I found out that I have some sort of circular reference which interfered. Next to that, I found that using subject's is really making this stuff complex. However, I need the functionality.

Comment: @ErwinOkken if you need the subject functionality I would follow the redux pattern / ngrx library. Basically you subscribe to the subject (manually or through the async pipe). And dispatch another method that makes the api call and pushes the result to the subject. So essentially what you had but split up.